# Create a symlink to a programme

Tags: python, symlink

Suppose I am in ~/programming/ass1 and the executable is in ~/programming/ass1/seattle/seattle_repy/repy.py.

I tried to create a symlink like so

```
ln -s seattle/seattle_repy/repy.py repy
```

to be able to type

```
python repy restrictions.test example.1.1.repy
```

instead of

```
python seattle/seattle_repy/repy.py restrictions.test example.1.1.repy
```

But it didn't work (I get "python: can't open file '/home/philipp/Desktop/Uni/NTM/UE/Uebungsblatt 3/safe_check.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory").
So repy.py can't find safe_check.py.

Is this possible at all?

Cheers,
Philipp

Comment: WHere is safe_check.py and how do you call it

Comment: It's also in seattle/seattle_repy/ and it's called by repy.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to frob `sys.path` to add the path containing the modules, but it's probably easier to make a shell script that calls `exec python ~/programming/ass1/seattle/seattle_repy/repy.py`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I solved it with a bash script in ~/programming/ass1/repy.sh

<pre>
#!/bin/bash
exec python ~/programming/ass1/seattle/seattle_repy/repy.py $1 $2
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips Ignacio and Mark.
I solved it with the following bash script in ~/programming/ass1

```
#!/bin/bash
exec python ~/programming/ass1/seattle/seattle_repy/repy.py $@
```

To finally get what I want I copied it to /usr/bin and created a symlink to it:

```
sudo cp repy.sh /usr/bin/
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/repy.sh /usr/bin/repy
```

So now I can just say`repy restrictions.test example.2.1.repy` and it'll work.

Comment: You should quote the parameters. Or better yet, use `"$@"`, which will pass all parameters.

Comment: Not `$@`, but `"$@"`. The quotes are important since they prevent arguments with whitespace from being split.

Comment: Generally, you should leave `/usr/bin` and `/bin` to the system and avoid installing stuff in there.  It often makes for easier upgrades.  You could use `/usr/local/bin`, or `$HOME/bin`, depending on whether other people might want to use it too.